# SQL - for loop duplicate issue

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Just wondering how I would change the following SQL so that the insert only happens for unique link_row instances.  So if the exact same values are pulled back in the seletc I only want to do the loop and insert the first time.

```
BEGIN   
      FOR LINK_ROW IN ( SELECT LINKTEXT, LINKURL, CORPID FROM LINKS )
      LOOP
          //Do insert here
```

When I run the script I get errors on the primary key violation as the same item is being inserted twice inside the loop.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use the `UNIQUE` or `DISTINCT` keyword to limit your select results.

BUT it would be far better to do the insert and select in one statement.

```
INSERT INTO <table>
 VALUES (linktext, linkurl, corpid)
 SELECT UNIQUE linktext, linkurl, corpid
   FROM links;
```

Comment: There is more to the insert that I didn't show, it then inserts into different tables depending on the values returned in the FOR.  Whats the difference between using unique and distinct

Comment: They are interchangeable, Oracle treats them the same.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `DISTINCT` keyword to select only unique records from the LINKS table:

```
BEGIN   
      FOR LINK_ROW IN ( SELECT DISTINCT LINKTEXT, LINKURL, CORPID FROM LINKS )
      LOOP
```

However, although I don't know the full extent of your query, there's usually better ways to accomplish tasks than using loops in SQL. SQL is declarative, and designed to work with sets, so you want to tell the database engine **what** you want to do, **not how** to do it.